# Windows 8.1 internet drivers not working (nor by cable or wireless), manefacturer only offers Windows 10 drivers, what to do?

Tags: drivers, windows-8.1, internet, network-adapter

The computer Fujitsu LifeBook E Series E549, serial DSBS008346, model ME14B, came preinstalled with Windows 10. I prefer 8.1. I used an old iso I had to revert it, which badly needs up-dating. Wireless Connection is not possible until up dating, this I expected...but that an Ethernet Cable neither works is a problem.

I browsed Windows UpDate Catalog and Cherry picked a few files from it, only a few run where most where simply open the folder, showing various but no executable file within. I moved these files from a different computer to the computer in question, but was not able to resolve it like this (likely from lack of vigirious excercise on my part).

As much as I usually prefer a trial-by-error approach to solve all computer issues, time has me ask this question: what the heck do I do. Simply, I need options. Is there an unofficial drive provider that solves issues like this--I assume the computer was designed with the expectation to only be used with Windows 10, and many dislike it. Or how would I find exactly the files I need to make this computer function with internet? You get the idea. Installing Windows 10 or a new 8.1 iso is a last resort, prefer to converve data.

EDIT: Since the last sentence was not enough, nooo, Windows 10 sucky sucky boogey boogey, no 10, say no to 10

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows8ISO

Comment: Windows 8.1 is past end of life for main stream support and is only getting extended (security support) now. Windows 10 works much better, so it may be time to move up.

Comment: If you need to reinstall Windows 10, _just in case_, (reboot the machine and press F-12 before Windows boots and choose) __Reset__ to factory default...

Answer (score 0):

On a different machine, you could download the Ethernet ("Ethernet Adapter Driver (Intel)") and/or Wireless ("Wireless LAN Driver (Intel)") driver from the manufacturer's website:

http://www.shopfujitsu.com/CSPortal/supportsearch.do?srch=DOWNLOADS&Series=E%20Series&Model=E549&ProductType=Notebook%20PC

Then transfer the driver(s) to a removable USB device and then move it to your Windows 8.1 machine, install the driver and then complete a full Windows Update once you have access to the internet - this should get you all your other drivers.